# Select whole text with one click

Tags: html, css, string, text

I have a shareable link in my app and I would like to make it selectable in one click for the users to copy it.

How can I achieve that in a browser-native manner?
(I'm not interested in a javascript solution at this stage)

Is there an HTML5 attribute I can use?
Is there a CSS thing I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what you're after? On-click, this will be entirely selected! See the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qow12zbu/)

```css
#link {
  user-select: all;
}
```

```html
<div id="link">
i am some extra long example text i am some extra long example text i am some extra long example text i am some extra long example text
</div>
```

**PLEASE NOTE - You will need to implement this for other browsers in this manner:**

- Mozilla: `-moz-user-select: all;`
- WebKit (Excepting Safari): `-webkit-user-select: all;`
- Microsoft: `-ms-user-select: element;`

Read more here: [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

Comment: YES! Thank you very much :)